# Freeswitch - not hearable IVR menu

Tags: linux, freeswitch, ivr

So we have two numbers, both are using same IVR menu template. When you call on first number - you can hear IVR all fine, but on second it's silent. You can wait a bit and press a number on the phone - and it'll work just as it works on first number.

Where do I look to troubeshoot the issue? I'm not really properly familiar with all the setup.

OS and software are: `Debian 6`, `freeswitch` and `stun` for handling NAT connections through tunnel.

Comment: FS logs might help - you can compare the first to the second and see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

are those two numbers from different telephony providers? Maybe they use different codec settings and one of them has problems with codec negotiation.